# python, dynamic type hinting and pycharm autocomplete

Tags: python, pycharm, annotations, type-hinting, python-descriptors

I'm trying to get pycharm's autocomplete to work with dynamic type hinting in python. Let's say we have a descriptor that takes "type" parameter on `__init__` and casts the value to that type on `__set__`:

```
import typing as t

_type = t.TypeVar('_type')

class CastDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, type: t.Type[_type]):
        self.type = type

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, _) -> _type | 'CastDescriptor':
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = self.type(value)


class Test:
    a = CastDescriptor(dict)
    
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

test = Test(a=[(1, 2)])
print(test.a) # prints {1:2}
```

the code above works just fine, but pycharm can not recognize that attribute `test.a` is a dict, so the autocompletion is not working for that attribute.

the only working way I've found so far is duplicating the type explicitly

```
class Test:
    a: dict[int, int] = CastDescriptor(dict)
    
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

test = Test(a=[(1, 2)])
test.a.strip() # will be highlited as dict has no attribute 'strip'
```

Not sure if it is possible, but how do I show pycharm the final type of attribute that is passed as parameter to descriptor?

Comment: `test.a` is not a dict. It's a `CastDescriptor` instance. This instance does not subclass dictionaries or something either, so I'm not surprised that Pycharm isn't able to figure out that the functionality of `CastDescriptor` is similar to that of a dictionary.

Comment: as far as i understand, Test.a is CastDescriptor, but test.a is actual dictionary returned by `__get__` method

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that way. My Python VSCode extension considers `test.a` to be `CastDescriptor | list[tuple[Literal[1], Literal[2]]]`, which is odd too.

Comment: You need `overload` on `__get__` to get rid of union return type, then make this class generic in type. [This](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=fdc7372e2eaf6f193a3e9839954260a8) should be enough (but I'm not sure that pycharm handles this properly, don't have it installed)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll demonstrate:

- How to use Generic to correctly type the descriptor
- Pycharms current limitation in using types

TypeVars don't have the same scope as normal Variables. This means that even though you're using the same one in `__init__` and `__get__` they are not considered to be related according to the Pycharm type checker. Adding Generic to the descriptor definition will fix this.

```
class CastDescriptor(t.Generic[_type]):
```

This can be confirmed by performing the following in pycharm.

```
class Test:
    a = CastDescriptor(dict)
    b = CastDescriptor(int)
    a.__get__().    # Pycharm autocomplete gives options for dict
    b.__get__().    # Pycharm autocomplete gives options for int
```

This gets closer to the desired behaviour but `test.a` is still not recognised as a `dict` which I test as such:

```
test.a = [(1, 2)]
test.a.    # Pycharm autocomplete gives options for list
test.a = {1, 2}
test.a.    # Pycharm autocomplete gives options for set
```

The same behaviour is see even with the OP's work around of explicit type hinting. We've got reasonable confidence in concluding that descriptors are ignored by the type checker.

Examples confirmed using Python3.10, Pycharm 2022.3